# xPath cannot select by id contains

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

I have a dropdown element that i'd like to select, but for some reason xPath is not resolved , i don't understand why.
This is the html :

```
<td id="Vertical_v8_57849360_MainLayoutEdit_xaf_l195_xaf_l204_xaf_dviDate_Edit_B-1" class="dxeButton dxeButtonEditButton_XafTheme" style="-webkit-user-select:none;"><img id="Vertical_v8_57849360_MainLayoutEdit_xaf_l195_xaf_l204_xaf_dviDate_Edit_B-1Img" class="dxEditors_edtDropDown_XafTheme" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_88-f49pk" alt="v"></td>
```

and this is my selector :

```
$x("td[contains(@id,'xaf_l195_xaf_l204_xaf_dviDate_Edit_B-1')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is fine, but the html is malformed: the `<img>`child node of `<td>` doesn't have a closing tag, it should be

```
<img id="Vertical_v8_57849360_MainLayoutEdit_xaf_l195_xaf_l204_xaf_dviDate_Edit_B-1Img" class="dxEditors_edtDropDown_XafTheme" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_88-f49pk" alt="v"/>
```

If that is fixed, the xpath should work.